# Android Places AutoComplete

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement Android places Autocomplete in such a way that ill have two EditTexts of which one will get the a specific city a user is typing and the other gives associated areas that are in the city the user has chosen.

I want to implement this on a fragment

Comment: And what have you done so far ?

Comment: I've created the first where the user gets the city,the second part is the problem so that the edit text only bring associated areas of the city chosen

Comment: could you select the other EditText programmatically? if yes i would  recommend you to implement click listener on the first EditText and when the user select place - use that city to get associated areas of the city(from the first EditText ) - tell me if i was clear.